# Showing selected tabs differently with JQuery ajax tabs

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-tabs

I had tabs with preloaded content like this:

```
$(function () {

    $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').click(function () {
        $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        return false;
    }).filter(':first').click();
});
```

This added class="selected" to links and css made selected tab look different

```
<div class="tabs"> 
    <ul class="tabNavigation"> 
        <li><a href="#content1">c1</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#content2">c2</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#content3">c3</a></li>
    </ul> 
    <div id="content1"> 
         content 1
    </div> 
    <div id="content2">
         content 2
     </div> 
     <div id="content3"> 
        content 3 
     </div>
```

Now I`m trying to get ajax to work. Well It's working but I'm having troube getting Class="selected" to my links.

The js function with ajax looks like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        ajaxOptions: {
            error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                $(anchor.hash).html("there was a problem");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

How can I extend it so that it gives clicked link class "selected"? Similar to the preloaded content version.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you're using for the ajax version? All you have here is the static html version. Thanks.

Comment: With ajax the only change in html is that the links have href="somepage.html". And the javascript code I did give. Content loading is working fine, but I'm having trouble giving custom style class to selecte tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {  
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        ajaxOptions: {
            error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                $(anchor.hash).html("Laadimisel ilmnes viga");
            }
        }
    });
    $('#tabs A').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('selected')){ return false; }

        $('#tabs A.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');       
        return false;
    });
});
```

This worked.